# Method to modify content of a queue by having it reversed, using only a stack and standard API classes?

Tags: java, stack, queue

Ok, so I'm trying to modify a queue to have its content reversed using a stack. I'm a bit lost. I know it shouldn't take much code to write it so I'm hoping someone can help and make this a bit more clear. The inputted queue is random, I'm just using [1,2,3,4] to visualize.

The methods I can use are here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Thanks.

Just from writing this I am getting an error at `stack.push(queue)` which is
`The method push(java.lang.Integer) in the type java.util.Stack<java.lang.Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (java.util.Queue)`

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    q.add(1);
    q.add(2);
    q.add(3);
    q.add(4);
    ReverseQueue(q);
  }

  public static void ReverseQueue(Queue queue) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(queue);
    System.out.println(queue);
  }
```

Comment: So, you want us to write it for you? What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: once you pushed into the stack , then you have to take these out from Stack as it works on LIFO and stored them into the queue

Comment: My current code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    q.add(1);
    q.add(2);
    q.add(3);
    q.add(4);
    reverseQueue(q);
  }

  public static void reverseQueue(Queue<Integer> queue) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        stack.push(queue.remove());
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        queue.add(stack.pop());
    }
    System.out.println(queue);
  }
```

Comment: I don't think I can use removeFirst and addLast as they aren't in the basic api classes

Comment: I'm getting one error with this at `stack.push(queue.remove());` which is "The method push(java.lang.Integer) in the type java.util.Stack<java.lang.Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (java.lang.Object)"

Comment: Fixed. There bound to be a few compilation errors in this code, since I'm not in front of a compiler. Take the time to try and solve them yourself. That's also part of learning.

Comment: The running time of this method would be O(2n) = O(n), right?

Comment: Yes. It depends on how you calculate the complexity of the push and pop operations, but in any case it's O(const * n) = O(n)

Comment: How would I change my method to work for any incoming Queue (not necessarily Integer)? Would I replace `<Integer>` by `<T>`?

Comment: Yes, all the occurrances, as well as to generify the reversal method (or you'll get a compilation error)